# A cart with the provided ID already exists in the account

Tags: magento2, mailchimp

I am using mail chimp extension in my magento2 store. Suddenly I have noticed that my order stop sync there is just syncing stuck i checked log error is `A cart with the provided ID already exists in the account` so what i did to debug this error.

Answer (score 0):

As i have seen this error comes in Mail-chimp version 1.1.1.

Basically this issue comes because of missing

> $product->getTierPrice(); in model>api>products.php

So you just have to upgrade your module or just put this code patch to this file.

Hope this help you!!

Comment: where this line added

Comment: model>api>products.php

Comment: line nubmer? i downlaod latest extension but not see this code

Comment: once upgrade your module, it is exist then we will improve code.

Comment: first  i download this version 102.3.34 then?

Comment: can you please tell me your existing module version, then also tell me new version with extension name

Comment: "version": "101.2.34", this is old version currently for me now

Comment: Please upgrade your module version by replacing code directly in app/code

Comment: i upgrade but not impact

Comment: can you please show us some more details, so that we can help you out